# i want to replace ^M\n part by space in a csv file using sed command in linux

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, newlines

I want to replace ^M\n part by space in a CSV file using sed command in Linux.....

I used `sed 's/\n/ /g'` but it is only replacing \ and not the other part.....

To be more descriptive, i am using query like

```
| sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > file.csv
```

where the query result will be collected in csv file. but i can see that there are these `\n` characters coming in the csv file ...and i want to remove them. so ....i need to change the sed command accordingly ....that instead of `\n` i should get space characters......

Comment: Do you want to remove DOS line endings completely so that the result is on a single line, or do you just want to replace the carriage return (`^M`)?  `sed` can not replace the actual newline (`\n`) because it won't see it. To convert the file to a Unix text file, use `dos2unix` on it.  [Edit] your question with an example of what you have and what you'd like to get. Until then, the question is unclear.

Comment: Why must it be using `sed`? There may be better and easier alternatives.

Comment: Some (or decently) more background info would help. I faintly remember MS EXCEL using `\n` to break text within cells, so we might not be talking of full lines here.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue even after doing `dos2unix`. I was able to resolve this with the below code.

```
sed -i  "s/\r/ /g" <fileName>
```

- `^M` is `ctrl+r`, so replace `\r` by space in file

Answer (score 0):

To replace DOS line-endings with spaces in the file `file`:

```
dos2unix file
tr '\n' ' ' file >newfile
```

This first converts the file to a Unix text file, and then replaces each newline with a space.  The result is written to the new file `newfile`.

In one step (without modifying `file`):

```
dos2unix <file | tr '\n' ' ' >newfile
```

Slightly unsafe (as it deletes *all* carriage returns in the file even if they are not part of a DOS line ending (does not modify `file` though)):

```
tr -d '\r' <file | tr '\n' ' ' >newfile
```